# Uncaught exception 'Exception' PHP

Tags: php, exceção

Colegas. Ajustei o código. A solução foi baseada nos colegas colocando o throw new Exception() dentro do bloco try/catch e coloquei também fora da condicional if(). Vejam:

```
function cadastro($valor){
      $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo = '".$valor."'");

        if(strlen($valor) < 3){
        $erro = "O sabor não pode ser inferior a 3";
        }else{
        $sqlCadastrar = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO tabela VALUES(null,'".$valor."');");            

        }
 try{
      if($erro == true){
    throw new Exception($erro);      
    }else if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) > 0){
               return "<script>window.location.href='cadastrar.php';</script>"; 
               }
             } catch (Exception $erro) {
                 return $erro->getMessage();
        }  
}
```

Comment: Você está simulando um erro, logo, erro efetuado com sucesso certo? ou foi um sucesso inválido?

Comment: Acho que o teste que você está tentando fazer requer que você lance a exceção dentro do block `try`.

Comment: Foi um sucesso inválido. Caso o sabor valor seja inferior a 3 caracteres, daria um erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa mensagem é exibida na tela porque a sua exception não foi tratada, então um erro fatal será disparada para avisar isso, conforme explica a documentação.

> If an exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal Error will be issued with an "Uncaught Exception ..." message, unless a handler has been defined with set_exception_handler().

Esse código (estranho) de exemplo, simula o problema, o catch espera uma `DogeScareException` por uma `Exception` que é diferente do tipo esperado para o tratamento foi lançada e não foi capturada.

```
try{
    throw new Exception("WoOoOoW Exception", 2015);
}catch(DogeScareException $e){
     echo 'Caught exception#';
}
```

Outro motivo é o [comentario do Marco Aurélio Deleu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111709/erro-uncaught-exception-exception-php#comment232001_111709), o `throw new Exception(...)` deve estar dentro de um block `try-catch` do contario a exception nunca será tratada e literamente explode na tela.

Comment: Certo. Fiz como o Marco Aurélio falou, mas agora mesmo chamando a função, não aparece o erro.

Comment: Such exception. Very scary. Vote up. Wow..

Comment: @Jose.Marcos pode editar a pergunta com o código completo da função se não for muito longa?

Comment: Colegas, consegui. Coloquei o try e catch fora da condicional if(). Sem vocês não teria conseguido. Ajustei a correção na edição. Obrigado a todos, mas terei que escolher uma resposta ;)

Comment: @Jose.Marcos, agora entendi o erro, seu código entrava em `if(strlen($valor) < 3)` porém o `catch` estava dentro do `else`. Fique esperto que `strlen()` não retorna o número de caracteres mas de bytes, faça um teste simples(`echo strlen('ação');`. Quando seu código cair no `else` `$erro` não vai existir para comparação `if($erro == true)`. O PHP faz cast o tempo todo logo você não precisa fazer `if($var == true)` basta so `if($var)`